# Реализация задачи с использованием стека с++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, структуры, стек

Задача: разделить стек на 2 стека. В одном - чётные числа, в другом - нечётные. Запутался с реализацией функции просмотра верхушки стека с извлечением. Подскажите, где я ошибся.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct Stack{
    int info;

    Stack* head;
}*b,*t;
struct EvenStack {
    int info;
    EvenStack* head;
}*begin1,*t1;
struct OddStack {
    int info;
    OddStack* head;
}*begin2,*t2;


Stack* push(Stack* p, int n) {
    Stack* t = new Stack;
    t->info = n;
    t->head = p;
    return t;
}
int View( Stack* p, int n) {
    int temp = t->info;
    p = p->head;
    delete t;
    return temp;
}


EvenStack* pushEven(EvenStack *p, int n) {
    EvenStack* t1 = new EvenStack;
    t1->info = n;
    t1->head = p;
    return t1;
}
OddStack* pushOdd(OddStack* p, int n) {
    OddStack* t2 = new OddStack;
    t2->info = n;
    t2->head = p;
    return t2;
}
void OddPrint(OddStack *begin2) {
    cout << "Odd Stack: ";
    OddStack* r = begin2;
    while (r != NULL) { cout << r->info << " "; r = r->head; }
}
void EvenPrint(EvenStack* begin1) {
    cout << "Even Stack: ";
    EvenStack* r = begin1;
    while (r != NULL) { cout << r->info << " "; r = r->head; }
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int n=0, k, i = 0;
    cout << "Введите количество элементов: ";
    cin >> k;
    cout <<"Введите элементы: "<<endl;
    while (i < k) {
        cin >> n;
        b =push(b,n);
        cout << "Положили в стек:" <<n<< endl;
        i++;
    }
    while (t != NULL) {
       int x = View(b,n);
       if (x % 2 == 0) { begin2 = pushOdd(begin2, x); cout << "Положили в чётный стек:" << x << endl; }
       else { begin1 = pushEven(begin1, x); cout << "Положили в нечётный стек:" << x << endl;
       };

    }
    EvenPrint(begin1);
    OddPrint(begin2);
}
```

Comment: Слишком много всего разного. Вам нужна одна структура, описывающая элемент стека  и 2 функции с ней -- push() и pop(). Тогда сам цикл перекладывания мог бы выглядеть так `while (b = pop(b, &x)) if (x % 2 == 0) evenstack = push(evenstack, x); else oddstack = push(oddstack, x);`

Comment: @avp немного не понимаю. функция push согласно объявлению возвращает указатель типа Stack, как мы можем использовать для другого типа?

Comment: Используйте для всех стеков тип Stack

Answer (score 2):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь три раза решить одну и ту же задачу. Скорее всего, при написании кода вы почувствовали, что повторяете код (возможно даже использовали `ctrl+c ctrl+v`). Повторение кода это важный сигнал того, что вы делаете что то не то и вам нужно остановиться и еще раз подумать о решении задачи.

---

Я так понял, что вы хотите создать два стека - в одном четные числа, а в другом нечетные.
 Что такое стек?

> Стек (англ. stack — стопка; читается стэк) — абстрактный тип данных, представляющий собой *список элементов*, организованных по принципу LIFO (последний пришел - первый ушел)

В нашем случае важно то, что стек это сущность, которая не зависит от типа элементов. (Действительно, в определении не сказано, какого типа должны быть элементы). Нет определенного отдельного стека для строк, отдельного стека для целых чисел или отдельного стека для четных целых чисел. Есть просто стек, у которого элементами могут быть либо строки, либо целые число и т.д.

Вы пытались создать отдельный стек для четных чисел и отдельный стек для нечетных. Я предлагаю создать стек, а потом (в зависимости от нужд) помещать туда все, что необходимо.

---

Реализуем просто стек для целых чисел:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//структура - элемент стека
struct StackItem
{
    StackItem* next = nullptr;  //хранит указатель на следующий элемент
    int data;
};

//добавляем новый элемент на вершину стека
StackItem* push(StackItem* top, int var)
{
    StackItem* new_top = new StackItem;
    new_top->data = var;
    new_top->next = top;
    top = new_top;
    return top;
}

//удаляем вершину стека и возвращаем значение.
StackItem* pop(StackItem* top)
{
    if (top == nullptr)     return 0;

    auto old_top = top;
    top = old_top->next;    //теперь вершина - следующий элемент
    delete old_top;
    return top;
}

void print(StackItem* top)
{
    auto iter = top;
    while (iter != nullptr) //если iter == nullptr - дошли до конца стека
    {
        std::cout << iter->data << ' '; 
        iter = iter->next;  //вывели значений, переходим к следующему элементу
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    StackItem* top = nullptr;
    top = push(top, 5);
    print(top);

    top = pop(top);
    print(top);
}
```

Элемент стека - `StackItem` у себя в хранит данные(int) и указатель на следующий элемент. Реализованы базовые функции работы с таким стеком - push и pop. Советую разобраться в коде. Теперь, при необходимости, можно создать два стека:

```
StackItem *oddTop = nullptr, eventTop = nullptr;
oddTop = push(oddTop, 5);     //помещаем нечетные
eventTop = push(eventTop, 4); //помещаем четные
```

И нечетные и четные числа являются целочисленными и легко ложатся в тип int. Однако наш стек все таки оказался зависимым от типа элементов (например в него нельзя положить строку).

---

Если решать задачу дальше, то можно отойти от привязки к типу, добавив шаблонов.

```
template <typename T>   //объявили шаблон с именем типа T
struct StackItem
{
    StackItem<T>* next = nullptr;   //хранит указатель на следующий шаблонный элемент типа StackItem<T>
    T data; //хранит элемент типа T
};

template <typename T>
StackItem<T>* push(StackItem<T>* top, const T& var) //добавили шаблонную функцию push
{
    StackItem<T>* new_top = new StackItem<T>;
    new_top->data = var;
    new_top->next = top;
    top = new_top;
    return top;
}

StackItem<int>* int_stack;     //стек, где элементами являются  целочисленные значения
StackItem<double>* double_stack; 
StackItem<std::string>* string_stack;

push(int_stack, 5);
push(string_stack, "Hello");
```

В приведенном выше коде мы "отвязались" от типа в StackItem и в функции push. Теперь они будут работать для всех типов(с оговорками). Во время компиляции происходит инстанцирование (=подстановка) шаблонных методов и классов, т.е. компилятор смотрит какие типы используются для шаблонных методов и **генерирует** необходимый код. 
Мы используем класс StackItem для типов int, double, string - компилятор создаст код для трех классов и вместо 'T' подставит int, double и string. Также будет создан добавочный код для функции push для типов int и string (для double не будет создан код, тк мы не вызвали соответствующий метод push).

Следующей итерацией будет создание класса Stack, который будет хранить указатель на вершину (StackItem) и иметь методы push, pop, вывод на экран и тд

Comment: `StackItem* pop(StackItem* top)` поправьте (`old_value` теряете)

Comment: Да, спасибо) Хотел сделать по аналогии с кодом в вопросе и изначально у меня возвращалось это значение. Поправил